# How to get the levels for each item recursive?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetChildsEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    public Transform transform;
    int levelsMin = 3, levelsMax = 4;
    static int currentLevel;
    List<Transform> allChildren = new List<Transform>();
    static int oldLevel = 0;
    Vector2 scrollPos;
    public int levelNum = 0;
    public int totalLevels = 0;

    // Add menu named "My Window" to the Window menu
    [MenuItem("Get Childs/Get")]
    static void Init()
    {
        oldLevel = currentLevel;
        // Get existing open window or if none, make a new one:
        GetChildsEditorWindow window = (GetChildsEditorWindow)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(GetChildsEditorWindow), false, "Get Childs");
        window.Show();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Space(20);
        transform = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Transform to get childs", transform, typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;

        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(transform == null);
        currentLevel = (int)EditorGUILayout.Slider("Slider", currentLevel, levelsMin, levelsMax);
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

        if (allChildren != null && allChildren.Count > 0)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            scrollPos =
                EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Width(400), GUILayout.Height(400));
            for (int i = 0; i < allChildren.Count; i++)
            {
                allChildren[i] = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Transform " + i.ToString(), allChildren[i], typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }

        if (oldLevel != currentLevel)
        {
            if (transform != null)
            {
                allChildren = new List<Transform>();
                IterateOverChild(transform, currentLevel, levelsMax);
                oldLevel = currentLevel;
            }
        }

        if(GUILayout.Button("GEt it"))
        {
            IterateOverChild(transform, 1);
            Debug.Log(currentLevel);
        }
    }

    public void IterateOverChild(Transform original, int currentLevel, int maxLevel)
    {
        if (currentLevel > maxLevel) return;
        for (var i = 0; i < original.childCount; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log($"{original.GetChild(i)}");
            allChildren.Add(original.GetChild(i));
            IterateOverChild(original.GetChild(i), currentLevel + 1, maxLevel);
        }
    }

    public void IterateOverChild(Transform original, int currentLevel)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < original.childCount; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log($"{original.GetChild(i)}");
            allChildren.Add(original.GetChild(i));
            IterateOverChild(original.GetChild(i), currentLevel + 1);            
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get automatic all the level depth for each object and display it in the editorwindow.

For example :

```
Object 1 is at level 0
Onject 2 is at level 3
Object 3 is at level 0
```

but i'm having some problems :

The code now the second method IterateOverChild display in the end 3 levels total but there are 4 levels. and how to display each object the level he is at ?

In the screenshot the arrows in red are level 1 the arrows in green are level 2 yellow level 3 and blue level 4 :

[image: levels]

I see two GameObject's at level 1 GameObject and GameObject (1) then 2 GameObject's at level 2 and two objects at level 3 and one last at level 4. this is how i see the logic of the levels.

I want to update the ui editor window panel with the objects and each object on what level he is at near each object to show the level number. ( I gave the objects names Level 1 Level 2 Level 3 Level 4 just to name them with my logic of how i see the levels ).

[image: levels]

Comment: It's really hard to read this question and understand what you're asking. I can't tell if you want to change the format of your debug statements, or if you're having issues populating the Editor UI panel, or if you're wanting to do a breadth-first search instead of a depth-first search, or something else. I will say that (1) your debug statements in your picture are not generated by any of the code you submitted, and (2) it's going to be confusing to look at with GameObject names if all your objects are named either GameObject or GameObject (1).

Comment: @Chuck to update the editor ui panel.  I have updated the screenshot image.  i gave names to the objects and show them in the editor window ui panel after clicked the button.  i want in the editor window to display near each object the level he belong to. i just gave it names level 1 level 2 level 3 level 4 as i see it in my logic but i want the code to populate the objects in the  ui panel window.

Comment: @Chuck near each object in the ui panel of the editor window on the right to add a field that will show the number of the level the object is at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How To Get Level of Any Transform?

This method completely shows the level. Just put the desired transform in the parameter:

```cs
public static int ObjectLevel(Transform current, int level = 0)
{
    if (current.parent) return ObjectLevel(current.parent, ++level);

    return level;
}
```

Similar method in a line:

```cs
public static int ObjectLevel(Transform current, int level = 0) => current.parent ? ObjectLevel(current.parent, ++level) : level;
```

---

---

### An Example...

Here that shows the level of all game objects:

```cs
public void Start()
{
    foreach (var _transform in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Transform>())
    {
        var level = ObjectLevel(_transform);
        
        _transform.name += ", level: " + level;
    }
}
```

---

---

### Result:

[image]